# How to query a table by using IN conditions in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Struggling to find an example of how to query a table to return rows with ids from a given list.

The query below throws on the inclusion of IN

```
var params = {
            id: '7deb3df9-552b-47a4-aef3-ad601f141d50'
        };

        var p = {
            TableName: 'players',
            KeyConditionExpression: 'id IN (:id)',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: buildQuery(params)
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "IN" operator with KeyConditionExpression, please see details in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671509/in-statement-in-dynamodb)

You may want to use [batchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html) instead of query, which is not so efficient though.

Here is how your params could look like:

```
var params = {
    RequestItems: {
      'players': {
        Keys: [{
          id: "7deb3df9-552b-47a4-aef3-ad601f141d50",
          rangeKey: "<range key 1>" // <--- if your table has a range key, you must specify its value here
        }, {
          id: "<ANOTHER ID 2>",
          rangeKey: "<range key 2>"
        }, {
          id: "<ANOTHER ID 3>",
          rangeKey: "<range key 3>"
        }]
      }
    } 
};
dynamodbDoc.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {

});
```