# Querying DynamoDB with a list in AWS AppSync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I am trying to build an AWS AppSync query with a list using `IN`:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index" : "my-index",
    "query" : {
        "expression": "id IN :ids",
        "expressionValues" : { ":ids" : $util.dynamodb.toStringSet($ctx.args.ids) }
    },
    "limit": $util.defaultIfNull(${ctx.args.first}, 20),
    "nextToken": $util.toJson($util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($ctx.args.after, null))
}
```

However, trying it out with parameters like:

```
query ListItemsWithIdList {
  listItemsWithIdList(first:20, ids: ["id1", "id2"]) {
    items {
      id
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

It throws an error:

```
Unable to parse the JSON document: 'Unexpected character ('S' (code 83)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: (String)\"{
    \"version\" : \"2017-02-28\",
    \"operation\" : \"Query\",
    \"index\" : \"my-index\",
    \"query\" : {
        \"expression\": \"id IN :ids\",
        \"expressionValues\" : { \":ids\" : {SS=[id1, id2]} }
    },       
    \"limit\": 20,
    \"nextToken\": null
}\"; line: 7, column: 47]'"
```

It seems OK to use `IN` for query comparison operator; however, how can I pass a `String List` as a parameter and fetch the results whose IDs are among those parameters supplied?

**EDIT:** Corrected variable name typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think AWS AppSync support `IN` just for now. I try to test your scenario and come up with a solution using `contains()` function.

[image]

Here is the result after query:

[image]

Another alternative solution is to use `Scan` (not recommended)

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
    "filter" : {
        "expression": "contains (:authors, author)",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":authors" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.authors)
        }
    }
}
```

Btw, AWS AppSync support `BatchGetItem` operation. You can pass a list of keys in a single query and return the results from a table.
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html
Here is an example and I tested it worked like charm:

```
## REQUEST MAPPING
#set($authors = [])
#foreach( $author in $ctx.args.authors )
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("author", $util.dynamodb.toString($author)))
    $util.qr($authors.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "tbDiary": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($authors),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}

## RESPONSE MAPPING
$util.toJson($ctx.result.data.tbDiary)
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but I avoid using `filter` section as it may corrupt the results when used with *pagination*. Did you try `contains` in **query expression** i.e. just where `author = :author` in your first snippet.

Comment: @vahdet Hope it is useful!

Comment: `BatchGetItem` looks decent, but I query the performance. Gonna test it. For pagination, it uses a different approach btw: UnprocessedKeys

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be 2 issues here:

- Your arguments in the `listItemsWithIdList` query accepts an argument named `userIds`. You have `$ctx.args.ids)` in your Resolver template. You need use the same argument name in both places.
- When you use `$util.dynamodb.toStringSet` in your Mapping Template, like you see in the error, it gets transformed to `{ \":ids\" : {SS=[id1, id2]} }`. However, you want the id values to be contained within quotes. AWS AppSync provides another utility method for this purpose. You can change your template to use `$util.dynamodb.toStringSetJson`, which then gets converted to `{ \":ids\" : {SS=[\"id1\", \"id2\"]} }`.

Let me know if this resolved your issue. Here is the reference to the [Resolver Mapping Template Utilities.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html)

Comment: Thanks, I removed the ambiguation caused by userIds / ids from the question. Tried `$util.dynamodb.toStringSetJson` but then the error became `Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Syntax error; token: \":userIds\", near: \"IN :userIds`. I guess `IN` is not allowed for query, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751240/4636715) also tells about it.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have already resolved it. However, there are two issues in your setup:

This has to be a filter expression and since you don't have a key condition, this may even have to be a scan instead of a query

Then there are syntax issues (which is what the error is really because of):
In the EXPRESSION, add parentheses to the variable 
"expression": "id IN (:ids"),

And in EXPRESSION VALUES use toStringSetJson instead of toStringSet
"expressionValues" : { ":ids" : $util.dynamodb.toStringSetJson($ctx.args.ids) }

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I avoided `Scan` was its `filter` is applied after the pagination (see the usage of `limit` and `nextToken` in the OP). You cannot decently get first, let's say 5 results, it may return 3 out of total 10 with `Scan`.