# Query dynamodb db list items with IN clause

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb table whose items have below structures.

```
{
    "url": "some-url1",
    "dependencies": [
        "dependency-1",
        "dependency-2",
        "dependency-3",
        "dependency-4"
    ],
    "status": "active"
}

{
    "url": "some-url2",
    "dependencies": [
        "dependency-2",
    ],
    "status": "inactive"
}

{
    "url": "some-url3",
    "dependencies": [
        "dependency-1",
    ],
    "status": "active"
}
```

Here, `url` is defined as the partition key and there is no sort key.
The query which needs to run needs to find all the records with a specific dependency and status.
For example - find all the records for whom dependency-1 is present in dependencies list and whose status is active.

So for the above records, record 1st and 3rd should be returned.

Do I need to set GSI on dependencies or is this something which cannot be done in dynamodb ?

Comment: Does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671509/in-statement-in-dynamodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a GSI on a nested value. You can however create a GSI on `status` but you would need to be careful as it has a low cardinality meaning you could limit your throughput to 1000 writes per second if all of your items being written to the table have the same status. Of course if you never intend to scale that high then it's no issue.

Your other option is to use a `Scan` where you read your entire data set and use a `FilterExpression` to filter based on `dependency` and `status`.

Depending on the SDK you use you can find some example operations here:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/tree/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples

Comment: I did the same. Created a GSI on status and using filter expressions to filter on dependencies. I think this shouldn't be a problem as this is not going to be a write heavy table .